# Comparing two juxtaposed elements by way of clause inversion?

Tags: clauses, subject-verb-inversion

What is this sort of sentence/style/literary device called?  I'm sure it has a name.

> There is no love without forgiveness, and there is no forgiveness
>   without love.

It appears that a point is being inverted to circularly tie to the initial point.  I just don't know how to label this device.

Perhaps some more context:

> There is no ice cream without vanilla, and there is no vanilla without ice
>   cream.

or

> Cookies are good, but there is no good without cookies.

I'd clarify this better if I had a clue of what's actually going on here, but to help you understand: people usually create statements this way to sound wise and/or righteous while causing a person to think (and it's usually a trivial attempt, for the record).  It's a cliche style.

Comment: I see the structure as a form of antimetabole but that wouldn't demand the conditional logic in your example.

Comment: Oh my God. Thank you.  You can post that as an answer.  I was looking for "antimetabole."  Sweet.  I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is that of an [antimetabole](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-antimetabole.htm).